# Visual Studio 2010 forgets custom editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel.

I'm also working with XAF (the application framework from DevExpress).

I right-click a Model.xafml (XML) file, choose "Open With...", then choose "Automatic Editor Selector (XML)" in the "Choose the Program..." list.

I click "Set as Default".  The default changes as expected.

I click OK.  The XML file opens in the Model Editor (custom editor) as expected.

I close the custom editor window.

I then right-click the Model.xafml file and choose Open, expecting to see the custom editor I just set as the default.

Doesn't work.  Instead, I see the raw XML file.

If I right-click again and choose "Open With..." again, and see that the default editor has been set back to "Project Default Editor".

It looks like Visual Studio has forgotten the default editor I just set.

I am logged in to Windows Vista as an Admin.  I tried explicitly running VS as Admin, just in case there's a permissions problem writing the default.  Didn't help.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in VS that prevents it from storing the default editor?

I already Googled this question and found no results.

Thanks in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found the solution here http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B147806.aspx

"The steps to fix this issue are:

-Rightclick the affected project.
-Choose "Unload Project" from the menu.
-Rightclick the unloaded project in the Solution Explorer once more.
-Choose "Edit "
-The project file is now opened as an editable XML file.
-Locate the following XML:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Model.DesignedDiffs.xafml">
  <SubType>Designer<SubType>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

-Remove the line

```
<SubType>Designer<SubType>
```

-Save the file.
-Rightclick the project once more in the Solution Explorer.
-Choose "Load "

Opening the model will now work, the "(project default editor)" entry is gone from the "Open with.." list and the "Xaf Model Editor" should be the the default."